# WHat does Lambda do in this code (python keras)?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, stylegan

```
def AdaIN(x):
    #Normalize x[0] (image representation)
    mean = K.mean(x[0], axis = [1, 2], keepdims = True)
    std = K.std(x[0], axis = [1, 2], keepdims = True) + 1e-7
    y = (x[0] - mean) / std
    
    #Reshape scale and bias parameters
    pool_shape = [-1, 1, 1, y.shape[-1]]
    scale = K.reshape(x[1], pool_shape)
    bias = K.reshape(x[2], pool_shape)#Multiply by x[1] (GAMMA) and add x[2] (BETA)
    return y * scale + bias

    

def g_block(input_tensor, latent_vector, filters):
    gamma = Dense(filters, bias_initializer = 'ones')(latent_vector)
    beta = Dense(filters)(latent_vector)
    
    out = UpSampling2D()(input_tensor)
    out = Conv2D(filters, 3, padding = 'same')(out)
    out = Lambda(AdaIN)([out, gamma, beta])
    out = Activation('relu')(out)
    
    return out
```

Please see code above. I am currently studying styleGAN. I am trying to convert this code into pytorch but I cant seem to understand what does Lambda do in g_block. AdaIN needs only one input based on its declaration but some how is gamma and beta also used as input? Please inform me what does the Lambda do in this code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lambda](https://blog.paperspace.com/working-with-the-lambda-layer-in-keras/) layers in `keras` are used to call custom functions inside the model. In `g_block`  `Lambda` calls `AdaIN` function and passes `out, gamma, beta` as arguments inside a list. And `AdaIN` function receives these 3 tensors encapsulated within a single list as `x`. And also those tensors are accessed inside `AdaIN` function by indexing list `x`(x[0], x[1], x[2]).

Here's `pytorch` equivalent:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class AdaIN(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, out, gamma, beta):
        bs, ch = out.size()[:2]
        mean   = out.reshape(bs, ch, -1).mean(dim=2).reshape(bs, ch, 1, 1)
        std    = out.reshape(bs, ch, -1).std(dim=2).reshape(bs, ch, 1, 1) + 1e-7
        y      = (out - mean) / std
        bias   = beta.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).expand_as(out)
        scale  = gamma.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).expand_as(out)
        return y * scale + bias

           

class g_block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, filters, latent_vector_shape, input_tensor_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.gamma = nn.Linear(in_features = latent_vector_shape, out_features = filters)
        # Initializes all bias to 1
        self.gamma.bias.data = torch.ones(filters)
        self.beta  = nn.Linear(in_features = latent_vector_shape, out_features = filters)
        # calculate appropriate padding 
        self.conv  = nn.Conv2d(input_tensor_channels, filters, 3, 1, padding=1)# calc padding
        self.adain = AdaIN()

    def forward(self, input_tensor, latent_vector):
        gamma = self.gamma(latent_vector)
        beta  = self.beta(latent_vector)
        # check default interpolation mode in keras and replace mode below if different
        out   = F.interpolate(input_tensor, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest') 
        out   = self.conv(out)
        out   = self.adain(out, gamma, beta)
        out   = torch.relu(out)        
        return out

# Sample:
input_tensor  = torch.randn((1, 3, 10, 10))
latent_vector = torch.randn((1, 5))
g   = g_block(3, latent_vector.shape[1], input_tensor.shape[1])
out = g(input_tensor, latent_vector)
print(out)
```

Note: you need to pass `latent_vector` and `input_tensor` shapes while creating `g_block`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I now understand it. Thank you very much!